# How make Watson conversation recognize the time?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

In the case I'm trying to see if it is possible or if there is a way to make Watson recognize the period according to the time.

- If the `conversation_start` By night time Watson say: Good evening!
- If the `conversation_start` By morning time Watson say: Good morning!
- If the `conversation_start` By afternoon time Watson say: Good afternoon!

Actually I create one entitie with `@time` and if user type good night, the entities save that and Watson responds Exactly what the user typed.

**And my response condition is:**

```
 @time, how are you?
```

**Example:**

- User: Good night!
- Watson: Good night!, how are you

See that it was the same answer, because I created an entity with these periods

**Check image:**

[image]

I want to knows If it is possible to do it automatically or if I have to develop some code to do this, and if possible an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As specified [here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/system-entities.html) you can use now()

see

```
{
  "conditions": "now().before('12:00:00')",
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [ "Good morning!" ]
      }
   }
}
```

Per @MichalBida comment, pls note that now() does not record the time on the end user channel but rather of the conversation service. A better approach is therefore to provide a context variable with the time on the end user time zone and on it apply `.before('12:00:00')`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dudi.

Comment: This will use the time zone of servers that are running the conversation service. If you want to use the time zone where the user actually is you need to find what is the time on client side (e.g. webpage integrating conv. service) and feed it to conv. service through `context` variable (`"evening":true`)..

Comment: Thanks a lot @MichalBida